# javascript window.open _blank address bar locked

Tags: javascript

In a button, I'm opening a new browser window with myUrl.

```
window.open("myUrl", '_blank','width=800,height=600,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,status=1');
```

When the new window appears displaying the new url, the address bar of the window now appears locked (read only) and I cannot modify the url.  Specifically I wanted to be able to easily skip between /name=mark to /name=sally at the end of the url quickly.

When I was opening this url in a tab, I could modify the address bar to render a different url?

Comment: when you say you want to "skip between /name=mark to /name=sally" at the end of the url quickly" do you mean you want to alter/control the window after its opened?

Answer (score 1):

The browsers updated security settings blocked the address/location bar in the window popups as readonly.

Earlier, we need to set the location=no for making them as readonly, but now by default they come as readonly fields blocking the users from navigating through pop up windows.

You can pass the parameter name=mark on opening the window itself to the window.open() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick up the `document.URL` and parse it

```
function yourParseFunction(str) {...}

window.open(yourParseFunction(document.URL), ...)
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_features) you can learn more about Window features and manage it.